# JavaScript throwing error while trying to overwrite file

Tags: javascript, hta

I have created and javascript code that is called from an HTA. The portion of the code which overwrite a file works fine when executed for the first time. But when i try to run it again on the same HTA thread, it throws an error 
"Permission denied". Its failing to overwrite the same file for the second time. Is this because the code using the file as an object and its not releasing it, If so, is there any way I can set the objects to null or something?

```
var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
if(objFSO.FileExists(MyPath)){
var objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(MyPath);
}
```

This is the block of code i am executing..

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTA

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function CreateMyFile() {
try {
var fso,MyPath,s,my_time;
var my_time = new Date()
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
MyPath = "C:\\TestFile.txt";
s = fso.CreateTextFile(MyPath,2);
s.Close();
alert('The File ' + MyPath + ' is Created ' + my_time);
}
catch(err){
var strErr = 'Error:';
strErr += '\nNumber:' + err.number;
strErr += '\nDescription:' + err.description;
document.write(strErr);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" onclick="CreateMyFile()" value="Create File Test"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```